# How to put variable into query in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing a problem how to put a variable from an array into a query String. Filter function works good, but Search function does not work. Variable id gets a id from selected user fine, but the next one vm.search doesn't do anything. I am pretty new to Angular an JS as well, so maybe I'm missing something really easy. My code looks like this:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.pil')
    .controller('userListController', ctrl);

ctrl.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'users', 'pilService', 'notificator'];

function ctrl($rootScope, users, pilService, notificator) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.filter = function () {
     vm.users = users;
        vm.users = pilService.filter.query(vm.data);
    };

    vm.search = function () {
        var id = vm.users[0].id;
         vm.search= pilService.search.query(id);
    }

}
```

})();

Thanks for any ideas!

pilService code:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app.pil').factory('pilService', service);

  service.$inject = ['CONFIG', '$resource'];
  function service(CONFIG, $resource) {

    var users = $resource(CONFIG.API_END_POINT_URL + '/pil/api/pilot/clients', {}, {
      query: {isArray: true},
      update: {method: 'GET'}
    });

    var filter = $resource(CONFIG.API_END_POINT_URL + '/pil/api/pilot/clients/filter', {}, {
        query: {isArray: true},
        update: {method: 'GET'}
    });

    var search = $resource(CONFIG.API_END_POINT_URL + '/pil/api/pilot/clients/search', {}, {
      query: {isArray: true},
      update: {method: 'GET'}
    });

    return {users: users,
            filter:filter,
            search:search
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Include the code of `pilService` as well. I think, it is function, but you're not calling it. Also, if it is _async_, then the returned value cannot be assigned like this.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve in the line below
var id = vm.users["0"].id;

Comment: @CrazyMac I am trying to access id variable on first user. That works and I get the value. There was an error on this lin - I corrected it but no change.

Comment: @Tushar just added

Comment: @JohnV. You mean to say the line vm.search= pilService.search.query(id); is not fetching any result? Are you sure there is a valid record for this id ?

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Comment: @CrazyMac Yes, I am sure there is a valid record. When I open console and set breakpoint on id = vm.users[0].id it gets value 123-456-789 which is correct.

Comment: @JohnV. take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my problem in not the best way, but it works. It seems that the problem were, that id was set this way as a String not an array.I changed my code into this:

`vm.search = function (user) {
          vm.id =  gpilotService.search.query(user);
        }`

This way FE sends whole user object with all of its arrays as params and BE picks up only ID.

Answer (score 0):

Your function name `vm.search = function ()` and the `ng-model` name `vm.search` both are same. May be angular is getting confused to do the binding action.

> Please define the name separately, then let me know it's working or not.

Comment: So you suggest to rename vm.search= pilService.search.query(id); to something else? I've tried it but didn't help

Comment: Nope. You need to change the name in your controller 
from ` vm.search = function ()` to ` vm.searchClick = function ()` . and also you should replace it in the `ng-click` in html side